# How to store data from forms (different users) into a database in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, backend

I am looking for suggestions to links or videos on how to store the data from the forms that users fill out on web app and later use that data from different user to output certain results. I have tried to research online and I have found couple of useful links but since I am new to react and web app area, I am getting confused on what would be the best way to go about solving this problem. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are thinking about getting into is called full-stack web development, if you are new to React I would encourage you to continue practicing with it for a few months and make sure you feel solid in the concepts. Understand the difference between [front-end and back-end development](https://blog.udacity.com/2014/12/front-end-vs-back-end-vs-full-stack-web-developers.html), React is used in frontend development, so when you feel comfortable moving on to back-end you could make the transition to learning [Nodejs and Express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction). Nodejs and express usually are coupled with a database, [mongodb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EE8ZTQxa0AM) is a common choice, but if you have a firm understanding of what a database is and its use you can really use what you're familiar with. In the end, don't feel pressure to learning everything all at once, take it slowly and make sure you feel comfortable before moving on.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice. As of now I feel comfortable with front-end and react since I have mainly finished the front-end side of the project. I think I will take the suggestion and learn Nodejs and Express.

Comment: @ShalinPatel Sorry for the late follow-up, but if the answer helped you please don't forget to market it as correct! I hope the sources I gave you have been a big help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should follow a general React course and a additionally a course that covers working with an API & React.

You'll find different courses on Udemy for example.